# SUM with where clause failing with "Subquery returned more than 1 value."

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying a query like this one, was trying in data.stackexchange.com and I got the error but I can't save the query since it has the error

```
CREATE TABLE #Stats(EarnedPrem INT, Code varchar(10), Ref INT, ReportPeriod varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(100, 'AB', 1111, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(200, 'AB', 1111, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(300, 'BC', 1111, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(100, 'XF', 1111, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(200, 'AB', 1111, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(300, 'XF', 1111, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(500, 'AB', 2222, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(600, 'AB', 2222, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(300, 'BC', 2222, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(900, 'XF', 2222, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(800, 'AB', 2222, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(400, 'XF', 2222, '201510');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(100, 'AB', 1111, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(200, 'AB', 1111, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(300, 'BC', 1111, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(100, 'XF', 1111, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(200, 'AB', 1111, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(300, 'XF', 1111, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(500, 'AB', 2222, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(600, 'AB', 2222, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(300, 'BC', 2222, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(900, 'XF', 2222, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(800, 'AB', 2222, '201509');
INSERT INTO #Stats VALUES(400, 'XF', 2222, '201509');




CREATE TABLE #LossHistory(SystemId INT, Amount INT, ID INT);

INSERT INTO #LossHistory VALUES(1111, 3000, 555);
INSERT INTO #LossHistory VALUES(1111, 4000, 556);
INSERT INTO #LossHistory VALUES(1111, 5000, 557);
INSERT INTO #LossHistory VALUES(2222, 1000, 401);
INSERT INTO #LossHistory VALUES(2222, 2000, 402);
INSERT INTO #LossHistory VALUES(2222, 3000, 403);


SELECT
distinct
lh.SystemId,
lh.ID,
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #LossHistory where SystemId = lh.SystemId) Amount,
(SELECT SUM(ISNULL(pss.EarnedPrem,0)) FROM #Stats where Code = pss.Code and ReportPeriod = pss.ReportPeriod) EarnedPremium,
pss.Code,
pss.ReportPeriod
FROM
#LossHistory lh
left join #Stats pss on lh.SystemId = pss.Ref
WHERE
lh.SystemId in (1111, 2222)
and ReportPeriod = (select MAX (ReportPeriod) from #Stats where Ref = lh.SystemId)
GROUP BY lh.SystemId, lh.ID, pss.Code, pss.ReportPeriod
```

But am getting:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

This is what is causing the issue, I believe:

```
(SELECT SUM(ISNULL(pss.EarnedPrem,0)) FROM #Stats where Code = pss.Code and ReportPeriod = pss.ReportPeriod)
```

This SUM is important because, for a result line, I want to get the SUM of just the EarnedPremim for the particular report period and code for that current line.

Not sure if what I am doing is possible?

EDIT:

I changed to this query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377639/tes22

But now, for example, both of these have the same value in the EarnedPremium colmn (2400). I want this to also be affected by the original Where clause:

```
WHERE
lh.SystemId in (1111, 2222)
and ReportPeriod = (select MAX (ReportPeriod) from #Stats where Ref = lh.SystemId)
```

1111  12000  2400  AB  201510

2222  6000  2400  AB  201510

So that for 1111 it would just have the EarnedPremium totaled for results matching 1111 (from the join).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe that will help; I added my answer:

```
SELECT
distinct
lh.SystemId,
lh.ID,
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #LossHistory where SystemId = lh.SystemId) Amount,
ISNULL(sumearned.EarnedPrem,0) as EarnedPremium,
ISNULL(sumearned.Code,'') as Code,
maxperiod.ReportPeriod
FROM
#LossHistory lh
join (select MAX(ReportPeriod) ReportPeriod, Ref from #Stats Group by Ref) as maxperiod on lh.SystemId = maxperiod.Ref
left join (select SUM(EarnedPrem) as EarnedPrem, Code, ReportPeriod, Ref from #Stats Group by Code, ReportPeriod, Ref) as sumearned on maxperiod.ReportPeriod = sumearned.ReportPeriod and lh.SystemId = sumearned.Ref
WHERE
lh.SystemId in (1111, 2222)
--GROUP BY lh.SystemId, lh.ID, sumearned.Code, maxperiod.ReportPeriod
```

Comment: I'm a developer not SQL guru (which is apparent) so I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible but the way I envision it is like it's looking through the results for the main clause `WHERE
lh.SystemId in (1111, 2222)` so when it runs the SUM for EarnedPremium I want it to only take into account the results from #Stats that match the main clause, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use:

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(EarnedPrem,0))
```

Instead of

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(pss.EarnedPrem,0))
```

Otherwise the select doesn't make much sens

Comment: ok I got it to this now: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377639/tes22 I'll edit original description with more info about what I'm trying to do

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand your explanation, more clear example of expected results should help

Comment: I'm a developer not SQL guru (which is apparent) so I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible but the way I envision it is like it's looking through the results for the main clause WHERE lh.SystemId in (1111, 2222) so when it runs the SUM for EarnedPremium I want it to only take into account the results from #Stats that match the main clause, is this even possible?